# C# string pattern in regex

Tags: c#, regex

What's the pattern of C# strings in regular expression?             I mean some pattern that matches anything that Visual Studio recognizes as `string`

This pattern is what I have tried but it doesn't work in all cases :

```
"[A-z0-9\\+;"]+"
```

*(of course this is not complete and there are a lot more characters that should be included but even here it's not working properly)*

It works for a text like this : `"kla\"+;s"` but in this case : `"a\"b + c"` it only matches to `"a\"`.

Actually I have testes a lot more but none of them were successful.

First of all I thought about this pattern: `".*"` which won't work properly in a scenario like this : `"a\"+;b" + "a\"b + c"` which is not a string in fact but two separate strings and a plus operator

Comment: Did you want to match all the characters present inside the double quotes?  Provide an actual string along with expected output.

Comment: In character sets you don't need to use the escape character. `[A-z0-9\+;"]+` works the same. This regex would match all letters and numbers, as well as the back slash, `+` , `;` and `"`. Is that what you're wanting?

Comment: @Flipybitz, Not actually. I haven't escaped those characters, I have escaped this character '\'.

Comment: Ah, I see what you were trying to accomplish, my bad I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match all the double quoted blocks.

```
@"(?<!\\)"".*?(?<!\\)"""
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5bG5/6)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\\)"` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match `"` must not be preceded by a backslash. In C# double `""` means a single double quotes. Another `"` is used just for escaping purpose. So this ensures that the starting double quotes must not be an escaped one.
- `.*?` Non-greedy pattern which matches all the characters non-greedily until
- `(?<!\\)"` an unescaped double quotes was found.

Comment: Your solution covers much more than mine does, removed my post. I'd upvote yours if I hadn't reached my vote limit :)

Comment: Cooool, It's fantastic, but can you explain about it a little more or introduce me some link to read about it? (read about regular expression you have used :) I haven't seen something like this before)